# Track progress of concurrently executed tasks

Tags: java, concurrency, timertask

I have a bunch of tasks to be executed in parallel. The tasks are grouped into stages and the tasks on each stage depend on the results of the tasks on the previous stage. Therefore, all tasks on a stage must finish executing before recursively moving on to the next stage. Here's the code:

```java
java.util.concurrent.Executor executor;

void process(Stage stage) throws InterruptedException {
    Task[] tasks = stage.tasks();
    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(tasks.length);

    logger.info("Execute {} tasks on stage {}", tasks.length, stage.index());
    for (Task task : tasks) {
        executor.execute(() -> {
            this.execute(task);
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        });
    }

    countDownLatch.await(); // Wait for all tasks to finish
    if (! stage.isLast()) {
        process(stage.next()); // Execute tasks on the next stage
    }
}
```

This is working fine, so far. However, I don't want to log the progress on each stage but rather periodically in a separate `TimerTask`:

```java
class Progress extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.info("Executed {}/{} tasks on stage {}/{}",
            executedTasksOnStage, totalTasksOnStage, currentStageIndex, totalStageCount);
    }
}
```

How would you pass the logged variables above from the `process()` method to a `Progress` object in a thread-safe manner? I'm familiar with simple atomic counters but in this case there are multiple variables updated together and then separately again. This is also a design question so I would highly appreciate if you could provide a code example.

Comment: Any reason to not accumulate statistics, etc. on the stage? It seems like the natural place to maintain your status information. A higher concept, the pipeline, could track which stage it is on. Then a reporting can simply query the pipeline and stage(s) for their execution details.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'll post my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution i can think of would be a `static volatile boolean threadOneStageComplete = false;` which is set true when thread one completes a stage and ending each stage with a while loop, which tests `!(threadOneStageComplete && threadTwoStageComplete && ...)` and lets the thread sleep for whatever time would make sense in you case. Make sure to set the variable false again when entering the next stage and maybe put each task into a class so you dont have a bunch of static volatile booleans but a volatile property in each task object.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so thanks to Ben Manes I came up with the following solution: I introduced a `Pipeline` object which holds an atomic reference to the current stage wrapped by a `PipelineStage`. The wrapper also contains a `CountDownLatch` tracking the number of executed tasks from the wrapped stage.

```java
class PipelineStage {
    final Stage stage;
    final CountDownLatch latch;

    PipelineStage(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
        latch = new CountDownLatch(stage.tasks().length);
    }

    int index() {
        return stage.index();
    }

    int totalTaskCount() {
        return stage.tasks().length;
    }

    int executedTaskCount() {
        return totalTaskCount() - (int) latch.getCount();
    }

    Stream<Runnable> tasks() {
        return Stream.of(stage.tasks()).map(task -> () -> {
            task.run();
            latch.countDown();
        });
    }

    void await() throws InterruptedException {
        latch.await();
    }

    PipelineStage next() {
        return new PipelineStage(stage.next());
    }
}
```

```java
class Pipeline {
    final AtomicReference<PipelineStage> stage;

    Pipeline(PipelineStage stage) {
        this.stage = new AtomicReference<>(stage);
    }

    PipelineStage current() {
        return stage.get();
    }

    PipelineStage advance() {
        return stage.updateAndGet(PipelineStage::next);
    }
}
```

Now the `process()` method from the original question becomes:

```java
java.util.concurrent.Executor executor;

void process(Pipeline pipeline) throws InterruptedException {
    PipelineStage stage = pipeline.current();

    while (stage != null) {
        stage.tasks().forEach(executor::execute);
        stage.await();
        stage = pipeline.advance();
    }
}
```

Finally, the pipeline can be passed to any number of concurrent readers, such as the progress logger:

```java
@Override
public void run() {
    final PipelineStage stage = pipeline.current();

    logger.debug("Executed {}/{} tasks on stage {}",
        stage.executedTaskCount(), stage.totalTaskCount(), stage.index())
}
```